# Define Types for recursive functions in typescript

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

I have defined a function in JS that keep taking functions(params => string) until it receive an object then it resolves the final string as a concatenation of functions invocations over the same object that is passed at the end

Here is the function

```js
export function prefixer(func1?: any) {

    function identity(x: any) { return x; }

    function curriedPrefixer(fns: any[]) {

        return function next(param: any) {

            if (typeof param == 'function') {
                return curriedPrefixer(
                    fns.concat(param)
                );
            }

            if (typeof param == 'object')
                return fns.reduce(
                    (prev, next) => prev + next(param), ''
                );

            return undefined;
        }
    }

    return curriedPrefixer([func1 || identity])
}
```

My problem is in defining the right types for its params and return type so the user of this function can pass a generic type(to help the function know what is the type of the final params object) and can help the user re-invoke the output of that function over and over.

Here's the function in a test case:

```js
test('should auto prefix', () => {

    let prefix1: any = prefixer((params: any) => `https://wwww.${params.domain}.com`)
    let prefix2: any = prefix1(() => '/path/to/item')
    let prefix3: any = prefix2((params: any) => `/${params.itemId}`)

    let params = {
        domain: 'google',
        itemId: '5444'
    }

    let resolvedString1 = prefix1(params);
    let resolvedString2 = prefix2(params);
    let resolvedString3 = prefix3(params);

    let trueResult1 = `https://wwww.${params.domain}.com`
    let trueResult2 = `https://wwww.${params.domain}.com/path/to/item`
    let trueResult3 = `https://wwww.${params.domain}.com/path/to/item/${params.itemId}`

    expect(resolvedString1).toEqual(trueResult1);
    expect(resolvedString2).toEqual(trueResult2);
    expect(resolvedString3).toEqual(trueResult3);
});
```

I've tried some nonsense ideas but didn't get any close and didn't find a helping answer regarding recursive functions in typescript.

Here's something I've tried but doesn't solve the types definition

```js
export function prefixer<T>(func1?: any) {

    function identity(x: any) { return x; }

    function curriedPrefixer<M>(fns: any[]) {

        return function next<S>(param: S | M | ((p: S | M) => any)) {

            if (typeof param == 'function') {
                return curriedPrefixer(
                    fns.concat(param)
                );
            }

            if (typeof param == 'object')
                return fns.reduce(
                    (prev, next) => prev + next(param), ''
                );

            return undefined;
        }
    }

    return curriedPrefixer<T>([func1 || identity])
}

// I still have to pass (p: any)...
let prefix1 = prefixer<{ domain: string }>((p: any) => `https://wwww.${p.domain}.com`)
let prefix2 = prefix1<{ itemId: string }>((p: any) => `https://wwww.${p.itemId}.com`)
```

Comment: a) don't write such a function, it won't work with functions that expect functions as parameters b) you'll need to use function overloading to distinguish between object and function input

Answer (score 1):

The first step to type this would be to write type signature of this prefixer without writing the implementation. It should look something like this:

```
// Utility types to make definitions below shorter
type Pojo = Record<string, unknown>
type EmptyPojo = Record<never, unknown>

// TData represents the object that is expected by all the previous 
// prefixer functions that you've already passed to this prefixer
interface CurriedPrefixer<TData extends Pojo> {
  // First overload: when you pass a function to curried prefixer
  // T represents fields that a prefixer function you now pass
  // to curried prefixer expects
  <T extends Pojo = EmptyPojo>(
    // You could change type of `data` to `TData & T` instead of `T`
    // if you want your prefixer function to have access to data that 
    // all previous prefixer function use, but this is less safe, I would 
    // recommend explicitly typing every iteration
    prefixerFn: (data: T) => string
  ): CurriedPrefixer<TData & T>

  // Second overload: when you pass an object
  (data: TData): string
}
```

You can now verify that this type signature works as expected, again, without thinking about the implementation for the moment: [see sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Now the only thing left is to fit the implementation to this type signature. It could look something like this: [sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcpWBAJgBSghmAA9oAeAWWQlMhFwGdkAlCBAeylwqbGwgA5gBpk6EAGsQnAO4gAfAuQBvAFDJNyCgGVa9CIxbsuPPgNCjxUmfOUBeNh268QEAG7QxE6XMUKAChgQAC5kAIAHMJ0ASmR7ZX5BIRiwjCwcAiIScihqZAAyZB0FDS0AzgAjACswqlTkJMs1AF81NToI7jBkGAkEMGBOEGQI7LJKABV9BmYnU14m4W8bPyUg-oBGAH4wgNw4MDgwybiExothOPUtXv7B4eQETGw8QmIJvJo6WeNnMyWVh8tn8QRATD2+0Ox2Q9XiiUuKQA2gBdBrpV5ZD65ajKG63LR9EADIYjNz0XSBCJwKBwAC2eyisMKxTOCOS6JemXeOUoNCKJTKBLuxIeZJ+FRqdQagKFBKJJMe5LAlMiNPpdWQAB9wpFomyLhzrnLhZpgDBwmAAJ4RCCcC3U2l0+KOADkCrFruNpp9T2G-GQblkADFwZCDkdNQKDYCYqj4r1wSbfZoiGBMCNnhk3uMcfzioFkynbkHQ0wAHRcYmHNVOmJF30xADcDdubVbWjTGcTFaIuHQSACHeFkSI7jEyoNYw8yAA1IGJY76TExK7XcPkM2G20fV2oOL6HL27c95muTnsVNAgrNshtsgkTeUcgwqj6+2APQf5AASQuwAAGwA5AAAs4E8ZAwE4UY4CYFg9WQOAQCtGJyzQtQAIgHppxyW9HBwz4KBUZBcE4Ok4FAMJAWQFpAkiA0AAMQLAMAIghL9ZE42RywAEhUCJy1I8jQBaSsyIY+tMOw3MACYEwI0hNiI5BgEgOkf1wKjERouiIkY5jWPYj8uO4viBNUiB1NwUSuDpCSMKw0ZcwAZnk2SAno+FkDXGIgA)